# Google Cloud Platform project quotas - By organization or by user in the organization or both

Tags: google-cloud-platform, project, organization, quota

I have a G Suite account that had only 1 user.  Then I added a new user, so now the G Suite account has 2 users.  The remaining Cloud Project quota for the new user is 12 projects left, but the quota for the admin account is 14 projects left.  Currently, the default number of projects allowed is 30.  (Was it previously 20?) But I don't know if that is for the organization as a whole, no matter how many users it has?

I added a second user, because I was wondering if creating projects under the new user would somehow be a benefit.  And I had assumed, that the quota limit for the new user would be an additional 30 projects, but it doesn't seem to be.

I was hoping that the original user would have 30 projects, and that the second user would also have 30 projects.  Is it better to have 60 projects spread out over 2 users, or 60 projects under just one user?  I want to know the "pros and cons" of each situation.  My intent is to be able to publish lots of add-ons that are each specific to 1 customer.

What if a G Suite account had 100 user accounts?  Would all those 100 users need to share the 30 projects of the organization?  I know that I can request more quota for the number of projects that can be created.

The documentation at:
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/limits

states:

> If you are creating a project within an organization, the quota on
> both your account and organization are checked, and if either one has
> quota remaining, the project can be created.

That obviously means that the quota on all the accounts can't exceed the remaining quota for the organization.  So, I'm assuming that there is BOTH quota limits for each account, AND each individual account.  But, I can't find any documentation explaining the differences.

What is the default number of GCP projects allowed by a ***new user*** inside the Google account?
It doesn't make sense to me, that if I paid for 100 new users, that the organizational quota wouldn't automatically increase. I'm just using that as an example.

Any clarification is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of Project Quota as follows.

1. According to Project Quota [1](https://support.google.com/code/contact/billing_quota_increase) for an account ( Billing Account)
2. Project Quota [2](https://support.google.com/code/contact/project_quota_increase) to the user account

The limit on the number of projects is determined by the billing account associated with the organization.

If a new organization was created with a new billing account in general they would have a limit of 30 projects. Depending on account history, along with account status this limit can be raised generally to 100 then to unlimited. If you need more than the 30 projects for a new billing account then you can follow the steps to increase the quota for the number of projects[1](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#managing_project_quotas) to increase the limit you will need to fill out the billing_quota_increase form[2](https://support.google.com/code/contact/billing_quota_increase). This request will allow you to request for a specific amount. So if you are creating multiple accounts and want each one to have a specific limit you can request one. Please note you will need to have a request for each billing account.